# Using Process.Start to print documents without showing Word

Tags: c#, printing, automation, ms-word

I am using the following code to print a word document from a C# app.

```
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(myDocumentsPath);
            info.Verb = "Print";
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            Process.Start(info);
```

This works fine Word opens and prints the document, and then closes itself down.  The issue is that Word opens visibly, despite CreateNoWindow = true, and WindowsStyle =Hidden.  I would have expected these two settings to mean that Word opened silently.

EDIT: Please don't suggest Word object model automation - I have many different document types that need to be printed (PDF etc) - it is just Word docs that are causing the issue at the moment.

Any thoughts?

TIA

Matt

Comment: What do you mean by Word object model automation? Do you mean Microsoft.Interop.Word?

Comment: @Jon: Word automation does not necessarily require the use of Microsoft.Interop.Word. It is just one way besides using VBA or COM. Actually, Microsoft.Interop.Word is nothing but a wrapper for the COM interfaces, and in fact it is not required for automation from .NET languages.

Comment: +1 divo. I remember, back in the old days, when we used to dream of COM interop.  DDE was as good as it got :-)

Comment: Is it possibile to set the number of copies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Word is free to ignore (and apparently does ignore) your request that it remain hidden.

See also [Why is my hidden process still visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537766/why-is-my-hidden-process-still-visible)

Comment: Yes, that is true. And that is why there is no way around COM automation if you want your app not being visible.

Comment: That's a pain - was hoping to avoid interops. Oh well...:-)